# Strict stationarity in multivariate time series

Tags: multivariate-analysis, stationarity

I am well familiar with the concept of strict stationarity in the univariate case (in which we have to have that the joint distribution to be invariant to time). However, I could only find weak-stationarity definitions when it comes to the multivariate case. Could you please refer me to some books having the definition of strict stationarity for multivariate time series?